# método Create do Sequelize não insere um campo do objeto

Tags: banco-de-dados, node.js, sequelize-js

Estou fazendo uma aplicação com Sequelize, e quando executo a função model.create({obj}), um dos campos não é inserido no banco.
O campo em questão é uma foreign key de outra tabela. A tabela em questão tem duas chaves primárias desta segunda tabela. Uma delas está sendo inserida, a outra apenas não.
Segue código:

coloquei apenas o código que tem a ver com a rotina em questão.

```
AppointmentController.js
class AppointmentController {
async store(req, res) {
    // Schemas validation
    const schema = Yup.object().shape({
        provider_id: Yup.number().required(),
        date: Yup.date().required(),
    });

    if (!(await schema.isValid(req.body))) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            erro: "validation fails",
        });
    }

    const { provider_id, date } = req.body;


    const appointment = await Appointment.create({
        user_id: req.userId,
        provider_id,
        date,
    });

    return res.json(appointment);
}
}
```

Model da tabela:

```
class Appointment extends Model {
static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
        {
            date: Sequelize.DATE,
            canceledAt: Sequelize.DATE,
        },
        { sequelize }
    );

    return this;
}

static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.User, { as: "user", foreignKey: "user_id" });
    this.belongsTo(models.User, { as: "provider", foreignKey: "user_id" });
}
}
```

A migration da tabela:

```
module.exports = {
up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable("appointments", {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        date: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
        },
        user_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            references: { model: "users", key: "id" },
            onUpdate: "CASCADE",
            onDelete: "SET NULL",
            allowNull: true,
        },
        provider_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            references: { model: "users", key: "id" },
            onUpdate: "CASCADE",
            onDelete: "SET NULL",
            allowNull: true,
        },
        canceled_at: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            allowNull: true,
        },
        created_at: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        updated_at: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    });
},

down: queryInterface => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable("appointments");
},
};
```

Exemplo da minha request:

```
{
"provider_id":18,
"date":"2020-03-05T18:00:00-03:00"
}
```

Retorno que estou recebendo:

```
{
"id": 81,
"user_id": 19,
"date": "2020-03-05T21:00:00.000Z",
"updatedAt": "2020-03-07T02:48:53.212Z",
"createdAt": "2020-03-07T02:48:53.212Z",
"provider_id": null,
"canceledAt": null
}
```

No console do VScode consigo ver a query executada, e a função não passa nenhuma valor, nem colocar a coluna 'provider_id' no insert. Segue query:

```
INSERT INTO "appointments" ("id","date","created_at","updated_at","user_id") VALUES 
(DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING *;
```

Tenho quase certeza que o problema está relacionado com essas duas FK´s usando a mesma coluna da tabela Users, mas não consegui resolver ainda.

Answer (score 0):

O problema estava no meu método de associação
Eu estava passando a mesma chave estrangeira nas duas referências.
Achei que precisa ficar assim, afinal são duas referências distintas, porém, a mesma coluna da tabela alvo User.

Precisei trocar o nome de 'user_id' para 'provider_id'(que é de fato o nome da coluna no banco).

Como estava:

```
 static associate(models) {
 this.belongsTo(models.User, { as: "user", foreignKey: "user_id" });
 this.belongsTo(models.User, { as: "provider", foreignKey: "user_id" });
 }
 }
```

Como deu certo:

```
static associate(models) {
this.belongsTo(models.User, { as: "user", foreignKey: "user_id" });
this.belongsTo(models.User, { as: "provider", foreignKey: "provider_id" });
}
}
```